Does the Bayes/Frequentist debate carry on to Machine Learning?
At least some Bayesians argue that updating priors based on evidence to arrive at the posterior (1) represents better our human intuitions (2) avoids many of the pitfalls of classical statistics (eg one does not need to worry about the fallacy of modifying the stopping rule based on the data, but stop whenever one wants and use a Bayes factor).
My question is whether the debate between Bayesians and Frequentists carry on to the field of Machine Learning?
In other words, consider the two (simplified) hypothetical situations (A) Frequentists are right and Bayesians are wrong (B) Bayesians are right, and Frequentists are wrong.
Whether A or B is true has a large impact on best research practice in various fields. Does it have an impact on Machine Learning?

Edit:
I am familiar with the Bayesian/Frequentist debate in the field of inference. The Machine Learning tools (those that I know) are about prediction.
'What is the suitable model for the way that the inputs cause the outputs' is a question that is not even asked in prediction. All prediction is asking is for the best function from the inputs to the outputs.
Does that mean that the Bayesian/Frequentist debate is largely irrelevant to statistical prediction, and (by implication) to the field of Machine Learning?

I don't think anybody really argues that Bayesian or frequentism are wrong, both frameworks have their advantages and disadvantages - the problem crops up when people use one set of tools (often for non-technical reasons) and misinterpret the answer to sweep the problems with the framework under the carpet.  ML is basically computational statistics, so there shouldn't be a real difference between the two communities.  Note frequentists use prior information as well (e.g. how to choose significance level) they just don't like to admit it ;o)

@DikranMarsupial Perhaps you could expand more on "ML is basically computational statistics, so there shouldn't be a real difference between the two communities."? I do not understand this statement, but that is precisely what I am interested in.

All of the "laws of statistics" apply equally to machine learning, it is just that ML people tend to be happier with larger non-parametric models and dealing with larger quantities of data (both requiring greater computational focus).  Perhaps a lesser interest in understanding the data generating process than on prediction?  There is no clear divide between statistics and machine learning AFAICS.  Coming from an engineering/ML background, I have learned a lot about ML from talking to statisticians ;o)

A lot of common ML practices (in particular regularization) have direct Bayesian interpretation while being difficult to square with frequentism.

@Durden You seem to confuse philosophies with methods.  Indeed, the theoretical basis of many so-called "frequentist" methods lies in Bayes priors.  Moreover, any pragmatic classical statistician will freely employ Bayes' theorem, provided the application can be justified. This is where the camps might part company, because what makes one a Bayesian is (in part) a willingness--indeed, almost a mandate--to include subjective probabilities in a model.

@whuber I meant this in addition to DikranMarsupial's point about frequentists using prior information, too, when choosing significance levels. Regularization of any kind fits this description as well. It wasn't meant to imply Bayesians own Bayes' rule.

Yes, you can look at ridge regression with Bayesian or frequentist hats on.  "because what makes one a Bayesian is (in part) a willingness--indeed, almost a mandate--to include subjective probabilities in a model" [emphasis mine] - I think ET Jaynes might take issue with that! ;o)  It is one of the dividing lines, some of the problems with frequentist approaches is that they don't use relevant prior knowledge, or they do, but it is not made explicit (c.f. the [in]famous "Bayesians-v-frequentist" XKCD cartoon).  Best to be comfortable with both frameworks as far as possible.

The choice of the paradigm for a given model always have some kind of impact on the result and the following interpretation. I have provided a very short answer since your question is very large and implies several aspects in practice (statistical properties, running times etc...).
But where I think choosing between frequentist or Bayesian may have the strongest impact is for small to moderate sample sizes. As you correctly point in your question, a Bayesian framework uses the prior to update our beliefs while computing the posterior. More your sample is small and more your prior may drive your posterior. The inverse is also true. I would suggest to use Bayesian approaches when the N is not large enough to have appropriate asymptotic results. Except for very specific use case in "finite" samples, ML or DL models are often built with a very large N, where the choice of the prior does not have a huge impact (except for shrinkage purpose where the prior choice is critical).
If you have followed my rationale, frequentist models could have interesting results asymptotically with better running times than Bayesian models. Both approaches converges when N tends to infinite and both are subjective in essence.
Some will argue for a specific paradigm independently on the data or the problem at-hand. This is a philosophical choice here. I argue for a more toolbox-oriented view of statistics where the choice of the model is driven by what you are aiming for ultimately.
If you precise your question depending on a specific aspect I would add additional elements if required.
EDIT
Regarding the question about irrelevancy of the debate between Bayesian and Frequentist methods, here a piece of opinion from my experience.
Firstly, I pretty agree with Dikran Marsupial's point where people in ML/DL are not very interested in model assumptions in the same way as statistical community could be. However, from a philosophical and practical view you have a strict difference for feature selection between a Frequentist LASSO and a Bayesian horseshoe for example. Both offer distinct appealing features. At the end of the day, you want good performances but also interpretability (that's my statistician side), and both paradigms have pros and cons regarding this aspect.
In essence, I do not think that the Bayesian/Frequentist debate is useless, I think most people in ML/DL misunderstand the advantages/disadvantages of a type of method in terms of performance and interpretability. Running a "random fancy" model with the hope that the performances are good enough to be used is what the community do not want. Informed usage is only possible by knowing what you are using. In this case Frequentist or Bayesian matters.

I have edited the OP, hopefully it clarifies
